# How to create tar file with only certain extensions but omitting server generated files with similar extension?

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, centos6

I have a folder of files and they will be in a pattern similar to this:

```
original.jpg
original.200px.jpg
original.300px.jpg
original.preview.jpg
original.slider.jpg
filetwo.jpg
filetwo.200px.jpg
filetwo.300px.jpg
filetwo.preview.jpg
filetwo.slider.jpg
imagethree.jpg
imagethree.200px.jpg
imagethree.300px.jpg
imagethree.preview.jpg
imagethree.slider.jpg
```

I want to ONLY select the original file (original.jpg, filetwo.jpg, imagethree.jpg) and omit the server generated files.  I'm trying to create a tar file of just those original files and not the dynamically generated copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tar -tf file.tar --wildcards '*.jpg' --exclude '*.*.jpg'
```

Output:

```
filetwo.jpg
imagethree.jpg
original.jpg
```

Just change `-t` to `-x` to extract instead.

To create the archive:

```
tar -cf file.tar *.jpg --wildcards --exclude '*.*.jpg'
```

Comment: And use `-c` and an unquoted `*.jpg` glob to create the tar instead.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah.. I thought it was about extracting :)

Comment: When I try to run that command I get this:

tar: file.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory

tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: @Hochmania Are you trying to create the tar file or extract it? The command to create the tar file is `tar -cf file.tar *.jpg --wildcards --exclude '*.*.jpg'`